# Etiquette on answers that complement your answer?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

So if another user adds an answer to complement your own answer, is it ok to incorporate the example into your answer?  I don't want to steal the other user's thunder, but I could make my answer better by adding an example.

Here is what is spurring this question:

[DAO vs ORM(hibernate) pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037251/we-really-need-a-dao-for-our-hibernate-application/4037336#4037336)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site license explicitly allows this.  Read the small print (bottom of the page), you have to give proper attribution.  Post two links, one to the author's profile, another to his post.  This goes a *long* way towards taking the sting out of him feeling you stole his answer.  Of course, don't forget to mark his post helpful.  It was.

Comments are a bit trickier since you can't link them, I've always seen the author's name being mentioned in the edit to be sufficient.

Arriving at the 'perfect' answer is the site's stated goal.  Some of the highest rated questions and answers are blends.

Comment: yes i upvoted immediately, and followed the advice of @Pekka

Comment: @hvg - it is not enough.  You also have to link to the poster's profile.  Going that extra mile (well, meter) is why this could work without creating friction.

Comment: how about now?  Also, note that I didn't actually take any part of his answer and put it in my answer....so is the link to his profile necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Hmm. I would tend to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037251/we-really-need-a-dao-for-our-hibernate-application/4037454#4037454) to the example, unless the poster gives their express permission to copy+paste the code.

Comment: good advice.  And thanx for the helpful link....;)  how did you get that?

Comment: @hvgotcodes use the "link" link underneath the answer.

Comment: facepalm...

Comment: @hvgotcodes one tends to overlook that. That was why I added the example :)